# TextField is losing users' input when rotating

Tags: ios, uitextfield, orientation

**PROBLEM**

When a user types into the TextField (landscape mode, or portrait) and rotates the phone the text is lost. Iam Using Different ViewContoller for landscape and portrait for same Page.

**QUESTION**

How can I prevent the loss of the text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the TextField text from one controller to another using `Delegates` or `NotificationCenter`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using different view controllers its obvious that textfield will lose its value as each of the view controller has its own textfield object. You can have a static variable in which in you can store textfield text in `viewWillDisappear` of each the the view controller. And in `viewWillAppear` of both view controllers you can set value from your static variable to text property of textfield.

Comment: You can have static variable in same class file. That should be it